# Trouble with introductory programming with C program regarding division and modulus

Tags: c, increment, division, modulus

I apologize for the poor title, and I wish to be more specific, however I am in an introductory programming course, and I don't have much programming experience. The problem I have been given states that I need to find the total amount of rope to climb a mountain. It has to accurately put out how many pieces of 100 feet rope are needed, and how many 10 feet pieces of rope are needed. The issue I'm facing is that when, say for example, the mountain is 611 feet, I'm unsure how to get the program to display that 6 pieces of 100 feet rope are needed and 2 pieces of 10 feet rope are needed. My code allows for simple figures like, 600, or 610, or 10 feet, but I don't know how to compensate for a figure that is in between tens. My code is placed below- Again, I apologize for not being able to make this more specific.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // declaration of variables
    int total_height;
    int hundred_feet_rope;
    int ten_feet_rope;

    //prompt user for input information
    printf("How tall is the mountain?\n");
    scanf("%d", &total_height);

    //calculations for how many skeins of 100 feet rope are needed, and how many 10 feet rope is needed
    hundred_feet_rope = total_height / 100;
    ten_feet_rope = total_height % 100 / 10;

    //output results
    printf("You will need %d skeins of 100 feet rope and %d skeins of 10 feet rope!\n", hundred_feet_rope, ten_feet_rope);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `total_height % 10` is zero when the height is divisible by 10 and not zero if the height isn’t divisible by 10. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine the amount of 10-foot ropes, just add 9 to the remaining height before dividing by 10 to account for the last strech:

```
ten_feet_rope = (total_height % 100 + 9) / 10;
```

Yet your problem statement is not quite precise enough:

- what if the height is 599 feet? Should the answer be 6 100-foot ropes or 5 100-foot ropes and 10 10-foot rope?

If the goal is to minimize overall rope weight, both answers are equivalent, but the first answer seems easier to use.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // declaration of variables
    int total_height;
    int hundred_feet_rope;
    int ten_feet_rope;

    //prompt user for input information
    printf("How tall is the mountain?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &total_height) != 1)
        return 1;

    //calculations for how many skeins of 100 feet rope are needed, and how many 10 feet rope is needed
    hundred_feet_rope = (total_height + 9) / 100;
    if (100 * hundred_feet_rope >= total_height)
        ten_feet_rope = 0;
    else
        ten_feet_rope = (total_height % 100 + 9) / 10;

    //output results
    printf("You will need %d skeins of 100 feet rope and %d skeins of 10 feet rope!\n", hundred_feet_rope, ten_feet_rope);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 5 100 and 9 10 will not be enough anyway. Did you mean 5 100 and 10 10?

Comment: @Broman: yes, good catch! I was fixing it as you were commenting :)

Answer (score 1):

To consume the additional 10-foot section of rope you require for anything *between* multiples of 10, you must push your existing number to account for that additional length of rope prior to the final division.

```
ten_feet_rope = (total_height % 100 + 9) / 10;
// here ============================^^^
```

This is common in computer science. Ex: symmetric encryption of an arbitrary amount of data using a specified block size .

At least I think that's what you're asking. I leave the task of accounting for this potentially bleeding into a 100 foot multiple to you (it can happen. suppose you had a 95 foot height; in that case you would want one 100ft length, and no 10ft lengths).

Comment: This will fail an input on the form `x99` where `x` is zero or more digits.

Comment: @Broman Did you read this answer? Specifically the last sentence ?

Comment: Nope, I did not. I stopped reading when I saw the bug. Good enough then.

Comment: This was it, thank you so much. I feel i overthought the problem a lot looking back on it. Again, i apologize if the question was worded poorly or if the code wasn't formatted accurately.

Comment: @MorganHilton Read the last sentence. You still have work to do. But at least you know how to round up to a nearest block, which I think was the root of your question.This answer isn't intended to solve your homework; only show you how to do that round-up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the modulus operator to see if the remaining number divided by 10 is bigger than 0, if so, it adds one 10 feet rope:

```
if (total_height % 10 > 0)
    ten_feet_rope++;
```